# Travelling around Jupiter

Tags: plotting, astronomy

Since we have soon historical conjunction of Jupiter and Saturn  I have prepared code with visualization planet Jupiter and Saturn with moons. This code first been prepared for version 11.3 and with this version it can be used as it is. Visualization of planet

```
JSP = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[
    PlanetaryMoonData[{"Io", "Europa", "Ganymede", 
      "Callisto"}, {"OrbitPeriod", "SemimajorAxis", "Radius"}], "SI"]];
a = Pi*{RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomReal[{0, 2}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 2}]};
b = 31557600*
   QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["OrbitPeriod"]]*
   Table[1/JSP[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 4}];
R = Table[JSP[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 4}];
c = Table[JSP[[i, 3]], {i, 1, 4}];
k = 3;
radius = QuantityMagnitude[
   Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["EquatorialRadius"], "Kilometers"];
radius1 = 
  QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["PolarRadius"], 
   "Kilometers"];
Xoblateness = Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["Oblateness"];
Xobliquity = Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["Obliquity"];
distanse = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
   Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["AverageOrbitDistance"], "Kilometers"];
angularvelocity = 
  Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["EquatorialAngularVelocity"];
texture = 
  ImageReflect[
   EntityValue[Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"], 
    "CylindricalEquidistantTexture"], Bottom];

planet = ParametricPlot3D[{radius Cos[t] Sin[p], 
   radius Sin[t] Sin[p], (1 - Xoblateness) radius Cos[p]}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {p, 0, π}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[texture], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

We have out this nice picture
[image: Figure 1]

Visualization of travelling orbit (we solve restricted 3 body problem)

```
    M1 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["Mass"]];
    M2 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Star", "Sun"]["Mass"]];
    Ra = QuantityMagnitude[
        Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["EquatorialRadius"]]*10^3;
    S = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["SemimajorAxis"]];
    ar = Ra/(S*149597870700);
    m = M1/M2;
    G = 6.67384*10^(-11); vS = 
     Sqrt[G*M1/Ra]; u0 = 16000; {ux, uy, 
      uz} = {0.28309789428056364`, -2.269693660804425`, 
      0.24765897137821516`}; tm = 2*0.007188414157797473;
    {x0, y0, z0} = {0.9987450742768228`, -0.00006988474848081634`, \
    -0.000015444353758731164`};
    eq = {x''[t] == 
        2*y'[t] + x[t] - (
         m (-1 + m + x[t]))/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
         3/2) - ((1 - m) (m + x[t]))/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
         3/2), y''[t] == -2*x'[t] + y[t] - (
         m y[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
         3/2) - ((1 - m) y[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
       z''[t] == -((m z[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
          3/2)) - ((1 - m) z[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
       x[0.] == x0, y[0.] == y0, x'[0.] == ux, y'[0.] == uy, z'[0.] == uz,
        z[0.] == z0};
    {xfun, yfun, zfun} = NDSolveValue[eq, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tm}];
    rt = RotationTransform[Xobliquity, {1, 0, 0}]; V = 
     rt[S*149597870.700*{xfun[t] - 1 + m, yfun[t], zfun[t]}];
{Orbit = ParametricPlot3D[V, {t, 0, tm}], Plot[Norm[V], {t, 0, tm}]}

Show[{Graphics3D[Orbit[[1]], Boxed -> False], planet}]
```

We have this picture with Jupiter and orbit around
[image: Figure 2]

Now we combine orbit, planet and moons in one scene. And here we have first problem with "OrbitPeriod" for moons. In version 12.0.0.0 it gives out period in `h` for "Io", "Europa", and in `d` for "Ganymede", "Callisto". Therefore we need to redefine `b` as

```
b1 = {8.8174971529112494627750732`3.9999565727231374*^6/3600, 
  4.392608409884539573243062`3.9999565727231374*^6/3600, 
  5.23208468377358490763874348`3.9999565727231374*^7/24/3600, 
  2.24299376347513480729423521`3.9999565727231374*^7/24/3600}; Th = 
 tm*31557600*
  QuantityMagnitude[
     Entity["Planet", "Jupiter"]["OrbitPeriod"]]/(3600)/(2*Pi);
```

Now we cam prepare scene and animation with traveler, planet and moons  rotation

```
frames=Table[Show[{Graphics3D[
    Rotate[planet[[1]], 2*Pi*Th*t/9.841666666666667/tm, {0, 0, 1}], 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> .25 {1920, 1080}], 
   Table[Graphics3D[{White, 
      Sphere[{R[[i]]*Cos[a[[i]] + b1[[i]]*t], 
        R[[i]]*Sin[a[[i]] + b1[[i]]*t], 0}, k*c[[i]]]}, 
     Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 
     4}]}, Background -> Black, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> Pi/4, PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.05]}, {"Point", 
     White, {20 radius, 0, 0}}}, ViewVector -> {V, {0, 0, 0}}], {t, 
  0, (1 - .0025)*tm, .0025*tm}];
```

Finally we make animation with `ListAnimate[frames]` or export it as a `.gif`

[image: Figure 3]

The problem is that this code not working with versions 12.1 and 12.2. How we can adapted code for these versions?

Update1. Second code with visualization of Saturn and moons "Mimas", "Enceladus", "Tethys", "Dione", "Rhea", "Titan" is differ from above since we need to show rings and also orbit around Saturn is not like orbit around Jupiter. The code is in notebook attached [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2143320?p_p_auth=QNj6dp8Q), and animation looks like this one

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Version 12.1 It seems to work. Start a new kernel and try again.

Comment: @DanielHuber It works, but what we have out? I have black rectangle instead of move.

Comment: Awesome example, my thanks and +1!

Comment: @AlexTrounev I ran your code and it works perfectly. I have version 12.0. I also exported the `.gif` file and it shows the animation. You can view the exported file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qeglessn9vlECAJ-OD8TMTxzOd5aux9o/view?usp=sharing) which I have uploaded. It might be possible that you are facing a display driver issue.

Comment: Also nice example !

Comment: Thanks for doing this! I tried the code out with Mathematica Version 12.2 Mac OS 10.15.7 -- the code and the animation making work fine. Please consider making a dedicated post at community.wolfram.com.

Comment: +1 Also runs with v12.2 under macOS 11.1

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Probably you are right about display driver. As I understand now macOS could be better for v. 12.2.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I will do at community.wolfram.com also for Saturn, Uranus and Neptune.  But there is still question about `b`. In v.11.3 "OrbitPeriod" been in second   in `SI`, but in 12.0, 12.1, 12.2 it is in hours for some moons and in days for other. Why we need to define `b1`.  It looks like  `UnitConvert[]` not working any more.

Comment: To convert periods to seconds you can use `UnitConvert[PlanetaryMoonData[{"Io", "Europa", "Ganymede", "Callisto"}, {"OrbitPeriod", "SemimajorAxis", "Radius"}], "SI"] /. q : Quantity[_, "Days" | "Hours"] :> UnitConvert[q, "Seconds"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  Thank you! It is very nice piece of code.

Comment: From the documentation for `UnitConvert`, "Conversion to a unit system will return a unit that exists in that unit system, not necessarily the base unit of that system". However, "UnitConvert[q, "SIBase"] typically converts all units to their SI base units". Consequently,  `UnitConvert[PlanetaryMoonData[{"Io","Europa","Ganymede","Callisto"},{"OrbitPeriod","SemimajorAxis","Radius"}], "SIBase"]` would provide the periods in seconds; however, the distances would then be in meters rather than kilometers.

Comment: I find it unfortunate that I can't award a bounty to a question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this discussion I been able to develop some general approach to the problem. In this answer I have demonstrated code to simulate journey around Uranus and Neptune. Code for Uranus

```
JSP = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[
     PlanetaryMoonData[{"Miranda", "Ariel", "Umbriel", "Titania", 
       "Oberon"}, {"OrbitPeriod", "SemimajorAxis", "Radius"}], 
     "SI"] /. 
    q : Quantity[_, "Days" | "Hours"] :> 
     UnitConvert[q, 
      "Seconds"]];(*Miranda,Ariel,Umbriel,Titania,and Oberon.*)
js = Length[JSP];
a = Pi*RandomReal[{0, 2}, js];
b = 31557600*
   QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["OrbitPeriod"]]*
   Table[1/JSP[[i, 1]], {i, js}];

R = Table[JSP[[i, 2]], {i, js}];
c = Table[JSP[[i, 3]], {i, js}];
k = 3;
radius = QuantityMagnitude[
   Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["EquatorialRadius"], "Kilometers"];
radius1 = 
  QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["PolarRadius"], 
   "Kilometers"];
Xoblateness = Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["Oblateness"];
Xobliquity = Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["Obliquity"];
distanse = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
   Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["AverageOrbitDistance"], "Kilometers"];
angularvelocity = 
  Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["EquatorialAngularVelocity"];
texture = 
  ImageReflect[
   EntityValue[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"], 
    "CylindricalEquidistantTexture"], Bottom];
planet = ParametricPlot3D[{radius Cos[t] Sin[p], 
   radius Sin[t] Sin[p], (1 - Xoblateness) radius Cos[p]}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {p, 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Texture[texture], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Next we need to define `rim` as image for rings (just copy and past image on the line `I0 = SetAlphaChannel[rim, .5]` instead of `rim`)

[image: Figure 1]

```
ringinnerradius = 34840;

ringouterradius = 50023; Sun = 
 Graphics3D[{White, 
   Sphere[{-40*ringouterradius*Cos[Xobliquity], 0, 
     40*ringouterradius*Sin[Xobliquity]}, .05*radius]}, 
  Boxed -> False];
Shadow = Graphics3D[{Black, 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {30*ringouterradius*Cos[Xobliquity], 
       0, -30*ringouterradius*Sin[Xobliquity]}}, radius1]}];
I0 = SetAlphaChannel[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoALx.jpg"], .5];
T = Table[{ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[1]], ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[2]], 
    ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[
     3]], (ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[1]] + ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[2]] +
        ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[3]])/1.5}, {j, 5, 30}, {i, 1, 748}];
rings = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 0}, {r, ringinnerradius,
     ringouterradius}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[T], PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2];
Th = 31557600*
  QuantityMagnitude[
    Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["OrbitPeriod"]]/(3600); Trp = 
 QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["RotationPeriod"]]; 
gr[t_] := 
 Show[{Graphics3D[Rotate[planet[[1]], 2*Pi*Th*t/Trp, {0, 0, 1}], 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}], 
   Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[.53]}}, 
     rings[[1]]}], Sun}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> .4 {1920, 1080}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> Pi/10, 
  ViewVector -> {{5 ringouterradius, 0, 10 radius}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0]}, {"Point", 
     White, {0, 0, 30*ringouterradius}}}]

M1 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["Mass"]];
M2 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Star", "Sun"]["Mass"]];
Ra = QuantityMagnitude[
    Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["EquatorialRadius"]]*10^3;
S = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Uranus"]["SemimajorAxis"]];

ar = 3 Ra/(S*149597870700);
m = M1/M2;
G = 6.67384*10^(-11); vS = 
 Sqrt[G*M1/(3 Ra)]; u0 = 6800; {ux, uy, 
  uz} = -vS/u0 {-.1, 0, 1.2}; tm = 0.00065;
{x0, y0, z0} = {1 - m - ar, 0., 0.};
eq = {x''[t] == 
    2*y'[t] + x[t] - (
     m (-1 + m + x[t]))/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2) - ((1 - m) (m + x[t]))/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2), y''[t] == -2*x'[t] + y[t] - (
     m y[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2) - ((1 - m) y[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
   z''[t] == -((m z[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
      3/2)) - ((1 - m) z[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
   x[0.] == x0, y[0.] == y0, x'[0.] == ux, y'[0.] == uy, z'[0.] == uz,
    z[0.] == z0};

{xfun, yfun, zfun} = NDSolveValue[eq, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tm}];
rt = RotationTransform[Xobliquity, {1, 0, 0}]; V = 
 rt[S*149597870.700*{xfun[t] - 1 + m, yfun[t], zfun[t]}];

{Orbit = ParametricPlot3D[V, {t, 0, tm}], Plot[Norm[V], {t, 0, tm}]};
Show[{Graphics3D[Orbit[[1]], Boxed -> False], planet}]
```

And finally we have animation

```
Export["C:\\...\\Uranus.gif",
  Table[Show[{gr[t], 
    Table[Graphics3D[{White, 
       Sphere[{R[[i]]*Cos[a[[i]] + b[[i]]*t], 
         R[[i]]*Sin[a[[i]] + b[[i]]*t], 0}, 2.5*c[[i]]]}, 
      Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
      ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 5}]}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> Pi/4, PlotRange -> All, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.05]}, {"Point", 
      White, {0, 0, 20 radius}}}, ViewVector -> {V, {0, 0, 0}}], {t, 
   0, (1 - .00501)*tm, .005*tm}], AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Code for Neptune

```
JSP = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[PlanetaryMoonData[{Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Naiad"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Thalassa"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Despina"], 
        Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Galatea"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Larissa"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "S2004N1"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Proteus"], 
        Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Triton"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Nereid"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Halimede"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Sao"], 
        Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Laomedeia"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Psamathe"], Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Neso"]}, {"OrbitPeriod", "SemimajorAxis", "Radius"}], 
      "SI"] /. q:Quantity[_, "Days" | "Hours"] :> UnitConvert[q, "Seconds"]]; js = 8; 
a = Pi*RandomReal[{0, 2}, js]; 
b = 31557600*QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["OrbitPeriod"]]*Table[1/JSP[[i,1]], {i, 1, js}]; 
R = Table[JSP[[i,2]], {i, 1, js}]; 
c = Table[JSP[[i,3]], {i, 1, js}]; 
k = 3; 
radius = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["EquatorialRadius"], "Kilometers"]; 
radius1 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["PolarRadius"], "Kilometers"]; 
Xoblateness = Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["Oblateness"]; 
Xobliquity = Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["Obliquity"]; 
distanse = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["AverageOrbitDistance"], "Kilometers"]; 
angularvelocity = Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["EquatorialAngularVelocity"]; 
texture = ImageReflect[EntityValue[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"], "CylindricalEquidistantTexture"], Bottom]; 
planet = ParametricPlot3D[{radius*Cos[t]*Sin[p], radius*Sin[t]*Sin[p], (1 - Xoblateness)*radius*Cos[p]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {p, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[texture], Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Image `rim` for rings visualization
[image: Figure 3]

```
ringinnerradius = 40900;

ringouterradius = 62302; Sun = 
 Graphics3D[{White, 
   Sphere[{-40*ringouterradius*Cos[Xobliquity], 0, 
     40*ringouterradius*Sin[Xobliquity]}, .05*radius]}, 
  Boxed -> False];
Shadow = Graphics3D[{Black, 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {30*ringouterradius*Cos[Xobliquity], 
       0, -30*ringouterradius*Sin[Xobliquity]}}, radius1]}];
I0 = SetAlphaChannel[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUp2p.jpg"], .5];
T = Table[{ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[1]], ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[2]], 
    ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[
     3]], (ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[1]] + ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[2]] +
        ImageValue[I0, {i, j}][[3]])/1.5}, {j, 2, 28}, {i, 1, 753}];
rings = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 0}, {r, ringinnerradius,
     ringouterradius}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Texture[T], PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2];

grn[t_] := 
 Show[{Graphics3D[Rotate[planet[[1]], 2*Pi*Th*t/Trp, {0, 0, 1}], 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}], 
   Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[.53]}}, 
     rings[[1]]}], Sun, Shadow}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> Pi/10, 
  ViewVector -> {{5 ringouterradius, 0, 10 radius}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0]}, {"Point", 
     White, {-40*ringouterradius*Cos[Xobliquity], 0, 
      40*ringouterradius*Sin[Xobliquity]}}}]

M1 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["Mass"]];
M2 = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Star", "Sun"]["Mass"]];
Ra = QuantityMagnitude[
    Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["EquatorialRadius"]]*10^3;
S = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["SemimajorAxis"]];

ar = 8 Ra/(S*149597870700);
m = M1/M2;
G = 6.67384*10^(-11); vS = 
 Sqrt[G*M1/(8 Ra)]; u0 = 6800; {ux, uy, uz} = 
 vS/u0 {0, 1., .01}; tm = 0.000323;
{x0, y0, z0} = {1 - m - ar, 0., 0.};
eq = {x''[t] == 
    2*y'[t] + x[t] - (
     m (-1 + m + x[t]))/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2) - ((1 - m) (m + x[t]))/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2), y''[t] == -2*x'[t] + y[t] - (
     m y[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
     3/2) - ((1 - m) y[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
   z''[t] == -((m z[t])/((-1 + m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(
      3/2)) - ((1 - m) z[t])/((m + x[t])^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2), 
   x[0.] == x0, y[0.] == y0, x'[0.] == ux, y'[0.] == uy, z'[0.] == uz,
    z[0.] == z0};

{xfun, yfun, zfun} = NDSolveValue[eq, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tm}];
rt = RotationTransform[Pi/24, {1, 0, 0}]; V = 
 rt[S*149597870.700*{xfun[t] - 1 + m, yfun[t], zfun[t]}];
```

Animation

```
Th = 31557600*
  QuantityMagnitude[
    Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["OrbitPeriod"]]/(3600); Trp = 
 QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["RotationPeriod"]];

Export["C:\\Users\\...\\NeptuneM8.gif", Table[
  Show[{grn[t], 
    Table[Graphics3D[{White, 
       Sphere[{R[[i]]*Cos[a[[i]] + b[[i]]*t], 
         R[[i]]*Sin[a[[i]] + b[[i]]*t], 0}, 3*c[[i]]]}, 
      Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
      ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, js}]}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> .3 {1920, 1080}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> Pi/4, PlotRange -> All, 
   ViewVector -> {V, {0, 0, 0}}], {t, 0, (1 - .005)*tm, .005*tm}], 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 4]